# Is there a way to get Sublime Text 2 to autocomplete HTML attributes?

Tags: editor, sublimetext2

I was wondering if there is a way to get Sublime Text 2 to autocomplete HTML attributes like in Aptana?

Answer (score 36):

Autocomplete is enabled by default when you use "<" and your tag and then hit enter. So if you enter `<p` and then hit enter it will finish out the tag pair for you... where you will end up with `<p></p>` and your cursor will be in the middle. You can change this to tab if you prefer by pasting the following into your Preferences -> Settings - User file:

```
{
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true
}
```

This will override the default value of false for completion on tab. Again that is only if you wish to use tab instead of enter.

Answer (score 12):

Hey you may try https://github.com/agibsonsw/HTMLAttributes or install trought package control package called "HTMLAttributes" ;). Its works for me. For example you type:

`<p` then press space bar then ctrl+space and you got list of attributes.

Comment: Your example sentence is unfinished here. Please use Markdown mark-up if you need to put HTML tags in the answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can try to use `emmet` package. It was made specifically for html&css code completion. For more information you should read [the documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/).

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same issue; although I use both plugin packages HTMLAttributes and Emmet, neither one provides the auto-complete functionality I was looking for that's similar to Dreamweaver's.

**Solution**: I found a package called [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/) that does exactly what I needed.

**Example**: I code html emails and do a lot of inline CSS. End goal:

```
  <td style="vertical-align:top;">
```

After installing SublimeCodeIntel, I typed `<td style="v` and a list of CSS properties starting with "v" displays.

[image]

Using my arrow keys, I select `vertical-align` and press `tab` to confirm, then type the letter "t" and a list of CSS values now displays.

[image]

I select `top` and then press `tab` to again confirm my selection.

Note: You can create predefined snippets for Emmet for undefined CSS properties but I wanted something "out of the box" instead of having to a) learn how to create them via the documentation (though I'm sure it's simple), and b) create a snippet each time I came across an undefined CSS property/value like `vertical-align`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is indeed what i was looking for - a plugin that will turn ST into light version of webstorm