# Auto closing comments HTML

Tags: html, plugins, tags, text-editor

I am searching for a plugin or snippet  for `sublimtext 2` or `texmate` which will automatically add a closing comment tag at the end of the html tag. For instance:
When inserting a div with the id  or class "test" the plug in would automatically add the closing comment at the end of the tag.

For example if I type the following into either text editor:

```
<div id="test">
```

I want the text editor to automatically add the closing tag:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: What is a 'closing comment'

Comment: Here is your answere ----->>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860181/is-there-a-way-to-get-sublime-text-2-to-autocomplete-html-attributes

You will have to create the element first, then put in your attributes

Comment: The closing comment is the html commenting tag such as <!-- / id name -->

Comment: Microsofts Visual Studio 2010 (and later versions) have this feature, in case you already have it on your machine